# Magento - How can I set a diffrent phtml for a block in an observer?

Tags: php, magento

Here is what I'm trying to do:
I need to add a tab on category edit page on the backend (admin panel).

I add it from an Observer file this way:

```
$tabs = $observer->getEvent()->getTabs();
$tabs->addTab('features', array(
              'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Related Pages'),
              'content'   => '',
));
```

The problem is that I do not know how to properly populate the 'content' attribute so I was thinking of getting the "Content" block and manually assigning to it a different phtml file.

Can it be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
$tabs->addTab('features', array(
              'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Related Pages'),
              'content'   => Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('[module]/[block]')->setTemplate('path/to/template.phtml')->toHtml(),
));
```

So you need to create you own block that will be rendered by the `path/to/template.phtml` template.
If you don't need any logic in your template you can skip the creation of the block and use `adminhtml/template`. Something like this.

```
$tabs->addTab('features', array(
              'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Related Pages'),
              'content'   => Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/template')->setTemplate('path/to/template.phtml')->toHtml(),
));
```

Comment: Thanks. Now for some reason I can't Click on the "Related Pages" tab (nothing happens). Nothing in the system.log and exception.log

Comment: Check if there is a js error on the page or if the page renders completely. Look in the generated source and see if it ends with `</html>`. Also use firebug to look at the responsed from the ajax calls made on that page. There might be a fatal error.